# sudo: apt-get: command not found

Tags: package-management, software-installation, gentoo, sabayon

I am trying to install aircrack-ng in my Sabayon 9 by the use of this command:

`sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng`

but it says:

`sudo: apt-get: command not found`

How to install it?

Comment: Sabayon is Gentoo-based, `apt` isn't really a package manager you should be using (see http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=En:Introduction#Package_Management).

Comment: Know your OS before hacking into other people's networks :-)

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like 
Run this once a week:

```
emerge --sync
```

And to install aircrack

```
emerge aircrack-ng
```

or if it is called different, you can search package database with:

```
emerge --search aircrack-ng
```

You should probably read about portage (emerge command) here:

http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=En:HOWTO:_The_Complete_Portage_Guide

Comment: Best not do that in sabayon, lot's of packages are out-of-dated on sabayon, after this you will never be able to use any official pre-compiled packages in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

APT is a tool used exclusively by Debian based distributions. 
Sabayon is based on Gentoo and therefore supports [Portage](http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Portage) (the `emerge` command mentionned in another answer).

However it also has its own binary package management tool (very similar to APT) called [Entropy](http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Entropy). Entropy has two frontends:

- [equo](http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Equo): command-line based.
- [Sulfur](http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Sulfur): GUI based.

You can use `equo` in a similar way to `apt-get`:

```
equo update && equo install aircrack-ng
```

(considering `aircrack-ng` is the correct name of the package)

Answer (score -1):

Which linux distribution are you using? Maybe you should use the correct package manager (like rpm, yum ....) or even install from the source code. I don't recoment you to use apt-get if your distribution is not based on it.

try: 
`sudo yum -y install aircrack-ng`
or
`rpm -ihv http://dag.wieers.com/rpm/packages/aircrack-ng/aircrack-ng-0.7-1.el4.rf.i386.rpm`
or
`emerge aircrack-ng`